# Can I create a Drop down list in my web Service, So that if someone using my service he/she can directly select values

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I am creating a Calculator web Service. In that project two fields are their which takes values and one field takes an operand and do the operation based on that operation.

But I want all the operand should present in a dropdown list,so that someone directly choose an operand instead of writing it.
I am using xml,jsp and java.

Comment: Ehh...why don't you create a dropdown and put your value into it? What is stopping you?

Comment: Actually I want to create a WSDL , if a client is using my web service he/she should see a dropdown . Is it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding you correct, you want a dropdown menu with different operands which are linked to different methodes?

Looks like your new to java web applications so the most basic solution is to use a switch case statement inside your java controller class in combination with a SelectOneMenu in your xml.

```
<h:form>
   <h:selectOneMenu value="#{controller.operand}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue = "1" itemLabel = "plus"/>
       <f:selectItem itemValue = "2" itemLabel = "minus"/>
   </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

your controller class could look something like this,

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Controller {

  private String operand;
  private int number1;
  private int number2;
  private double result;

  public String getOperand() {
    return operand;
  }
  public void setOperand(String operand) {
    this.operand = operand;
  }
  public void calculate(){
    switch(operand){
      case "1": result = number1 + number2;
              break;
      case "2": result = number1 - number2;
              break;
    }
  }
}
```

(not tested)

This is basic and not ideal. If you want to get more complex dropdown list you should take a look at 'jsf converters'. This is used to couple an object to a list item.
This would be interesting if you make a class for every operand and let it inherit from a parant "Operand" class. This way you could easily store a list op Operand objects and use this list in your dropdown menu.

Comment: I am appreciating your answer,but Actually I want to create a WSDL , if a client is using my web service he/she should see a dropdown . Is it possible ??